# Is the gradient of a convex continuosly differentiable function also a monotonically non-decreasing vextor function?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

The definition of monotonically non-decreasing is:

Suppose h: R^n -> R^n, and if

[image]

then h is said to be monotonically non-decreasing.

I know that if a function is convex and continuously differentiable then we have:

[image]
[image]

Then can I add these two inequality together to prove the assumption?

Comment: h is R^n -> R^n because f is R^n -> R and the gradient of f is thus R^n -> R^n. So that the gradient of f can be inner product with n-dimension vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by adding your two inequalities, we discover that
\begin{align}
&\quad f(x) + f(y) \geq f(x) + f(y) + \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x),x - y \rangle\\
\iff & \quad \langle \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y), x - y \rangle \geq 0.
\end{align}

---

Edit: Here are a few intermediate steps shown in more detail.
\begin{align}
 \langle \nabla f(y),x - y \rangle + \langle \nabla f(x), y - x) \rangle
&= \langle \nabla f(y),x - y \rangle + \langle -\nabla f(x), x - y) \rangle \\
&= \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x), x - y \rangle.
\end{align}

Also, 
\begin{align}
& 0 \geq \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x), x - y \rangle \\
\implies & 0 \leq -  \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x), x - y \rangle \\
\implies & 0 \leq \langle \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y), x - y \rangle.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! But why ⟨ ∇f(y), x−y⟩+⟨∇f(x), y-x⟩ = ⟨∇f(y)−∇f(x),x−y⟩?
And why 0 ≥ ⟨∇f(y)−∇f(x),x−y⟩ ⟺ ⟨∇f(x)−∇f(y),x−y⟩≥0? Is there any rule behind this?

Comment: Yes, in those steps I'm just using some basic properties of inner products, such as $\langle u, -v \rangle = \langle -u, v \rangle$ and $\langle u, v \rangle + \langle w, v \rangle = \langle u + w, v \rangle$.